# Is 'dur' another way of saying flat (b)?

Tags: terminology

I found this sheet music for a quartet by Haydn:

[image: Picture of sheet music]

As you can see, on the cover it says B♭ major/ **B-Dur** / Si♭ majeur.

I can understand the first and the third terms, but is B-Dur another way of saying B♭? And why?

Comment: Welcome to the world of "musical terms in different languages" :-) .   Wait 'til you have to learn German, French, and English tempo notations.

Comment: And of course Italian.

Comment: I wasn't really moll-ified until I learned minor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why note B is marked with H in Scandinavia and Germany?](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10195/why-note-b-is-marked-with-h-in-scandinavia-and-germany)

Comment: The answers are similar, but these are very different questions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

B is the German name for Bb (B natural is called H). Then "Dur" is the German for "major" (which again is really from Italian 'duro').

Comment: This is even more confusing than Si ( = B) which is pronounced like C (= Do)

Comment: ...And the opposite (minor) is *molle*, sometimes shortened to *mol*.

Comment: @Shevliaskovic In most languages, C is not pronounced like Si, at least not in German.

Comment: @el.pescado in most languages or in German? In English speaking ones, it does

Comment: @el.pescado - well, at least, tell us how it IS pronounced!

Comment: @Shevliaskovic: el.pescado said "In most languages", not most _people_ (as in your "English speaking ones"). Tim: C is pronounced e.g. in Hungarian as "tse:" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel)