# What are "Es", "As", etc. chords?

Tags: piano, chords, notation

I cannot find these chords in my piano chord manual and think they may have alternative notations.  What is an Es or As chord?

Comment: Might be sus4 chords if I had to guess off the top of my head. Can you post the context?

Comment: would be easier to guess if there was piano notation to go with it...

Comment: So, where DID you find them ?

Comment: @MatthewRead: why did you delete my answer? It was posted before the other (equivalent) answer by dennisdeems.

Comment: @MattL. I'm really sorry about that, I must have misread the timestamps.  I've upvoted your answer, I agree with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that it's probably a sus4 chord, but if it's hand-written, could the "s" possibly be a "5" and it's a power chord? Only other kind of far-out thought...

Comment: No, says "Es". Probably sus4 indeed.

Comment: Why is this chosen answer while other answers are clearly better? It's German naming for sure.

Answer (score 21):

Is this handwritten or printed?  Is the notation of German origin?  In German, the notes E flat and A flat are called Es and As.

Comment: While "-is" is the suffix used for sharp (i. e. C sharp is Cis in German), flat translates to either "-es" (Ces for C flat) or "-s" for other cases, like Es and As. Also, B is called H in German - while the German B corresponds to English B flat.

Comment: @david.mihola - the flat in German for A and E is 's'. Strange that there are Ces, Des, and Ges only. C flat being B, but in German that's B. B flat is just B. Confusing, if you're not German...  I need to know where on the stave the H line or space is !!

Comment: It's not just Germany, but some other European countries too (see [this answer](http://music.stackexchange.com/a/6664)). For us, the B/Bb system is the confusing one.

Comment: It is handwritten but looks much more like Es than like E5.

Comment: @Tim: Didn't you forget *Fes*?

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas: Then why is the the answer that suggests it means *E5* the accepted one?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - no, as my source has no mention of 'Fes'. F flat doesn't feature in many keys, whilst obviously it exists.Good last point !

Comment: @Tim And we even have Ceses, Deses, Eses, Feses, Geses, Asas, and Heses (rarely called Bes) for the double flats. Most of them are of course beyond rare, as you know.

Comment: These are not notes, these are chords as the notations appear next to other very obvious chords like Cm.

Comment: Except a few very special cases, chords are named for their root note.  "Es" identifies the pitch of e-flat, but also the major triad whose root is e-flat.  The presence of a C minor chord is entirely consistent with this interpretation.

Answer (score 8):

Could it maybe be German (or Dutch)? Because in this case it would mean Eb and Ab (i.e. E *flat* and A *flat*). And in this case 'Es' would refer to an Eb major triad, and 'As' refers to an Ab major triad.

Comment: c.f. this list of key names in different languages http://www.library.yale.edu/cataloging/music/keylang.htm

Comment: I think so. Indonesia seems to have picked it up from Dutch, and the examples you mentioned above are true for Indonesia as well.

Answer (score 7):

After doing a little bit of digging,  I found a [source](http://www.musicnovatory.com/chordsymbols.html)* that uses the s instead of the full sus symbol to notate a suspended chord. They always put the number next to it, but a sus alone indicates a sus4 so I would imagine that they would be equivalent. I would still like to see the context just to be sure but I think it is pretty likely.

---

<sub>* I don't really like or agree with a good chunk of the notation that this page uses, but shows the possibility of a sus being notated that way.</sub>