# what is the difference between writing and pronouncing of notes?

Tags: theory

what is the difference between note letters and pronouncing of them?
we write `C D E F G A B` but pronouncing them `DO RE MI FA SOL LA SI` respectively , I've heard that in many videos people call notes as they are written but in educational books and classical methods there is difference between note letters and associated Solfège.

Comment: When you are talking about written notes, do you mean the letter C, or the notehead written on a music staff?

Comment: @NReilingh I think he is referring to letter names in relationship to Solfège which depends on the scale used unless it is fixed do Solfège.

Comment: Methinks there needs to be more clarification with this question.

Comment: I mean letter C ,D,etc .this question was repetitive but I think could be useful for people like me , see the link below: [difference between note letters and associated Solfège](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4957/what-is-the-relationship-between-do-re-mi-and-note-letter-names)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do Re Mi and so forth are generally "movable".  In the key of G, G is "Do" and B is "Mi".  The tonic of the key is "Do".  Solfege is usually sung this way, with Do as the key note.  This is the "Movable Do" system.  If you transposed the song "Do Re Mi" (from The Sound of Music) to any other key it would still be "Do Re Mi".

In some languages, French for instance, Do Re Mi etc. are used instead of C D E.  This is the "fixed Do" system.  Do is C.  La symphonie de César Franck est en ré mineur.  The symphony by César Franck is in D minor.

If you want to say something based on the actual notes played, say for instance "The song goes F# F# G A A G F# E D D E F# F# E E in the key of D."  If you want to say something about the song without any reference to what key it is in, say "The song goes mi mi fa sol sol fa mi re do do re mi mi re re."

Comment: also see :[difference between note letters and associated Solfège](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4957/what-is-the-relationship-between-do-re-mi-and-note-letter-names)