# What is the meaning of two vertical bars surrounding notes?

Tags: notation

I am seeing notes surrounded by two vertical bars that I cannot interpret (see the first notes in the treble and bass below). I have checked the liner and Google/Wikipedia for ideas but cannot find a good explanation. Any help would appreciated.

These are from an Isidor Phillip finger exercise.

[image: note_with_vertical_bars]

Comment: The note shown in the duplicate is just a variant of the note in question here. There is also a more square version, as seen in [Meaning of a box-like symbol, sometimes with a line through it](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/124821/70803).

Comment: @Aaron - I guess its a variation of the first reference. So it appears that its a double whole note (8 beats). Thank you for the references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those notes are *breves* (double whole notes).  A breve has twice the value of a *semibreve* (whole note), four times the value of a minim (half note), or eight times the value of a crotchet (quarter note). A breve will completely fill a bar of 8/4.

Theses aren't seen very often anymore because they are too long to fit into measures with the time signatures that are commonly used today.

Comment: If you are in tempus imperfectus, yes. But you left out: "... half the value of a longa, or quarter the value of a maxima" (assuming modus imperfectus and maximodus imperfectus). Now, these are things you rarely see today ...

Comment: @Lazy *tempus imperfectum*, yes.  But I think that that's reasonable given the time signature.